# combining result of different regex pattern in one line

Tags: regex

I want to know how to combining result of different regex pattern in one line.  Below are the sample content of the text file that I am using.

```
#SET Account = a123-k
#SET Name = Tom Alek
#SET Account = hb15354j
#SET Name = Alex Payne
#SET Account = gd123-ff
#SET Name = Jerry Timbol
```

I can only out put one at a time with

```
regex = "#SET Account = ([^\n]+)\s"
regex = "#SET Name = ([^\n]+)\s"
```

The output below that I would like to have is in csv file with "," delimited.

a123-k,Tom Alek
hb15354j,Alex Payne
gd123-ff,Jerry Timbol

Is this possible to achieve only by using regex pattern searching or do I need to create a program like powershell?

Answer (score 0):

If all values follow the same pattern, you could do it like this:

```
regex = "^#SET (?:Account|Name) = ([^\n]+)$"
```

`(?:...)` are non-capturing parentheses. They let you group items without creating a *capturing group*.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/vY0zR8/1)